# How To: Redirect to a specific page when the user can not be authenticated (devise rails gem)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, authentication, devise

I just figured this out, devise's instruction are not the best. I've answered my own question below

goes inside lib

```
  class CustomFailure < Devise::FailureApp
    def redirect_url
       new_user_session_url(:subdomain => 'secure')
    end

    # You need to override respond to eliminate recall
    def respond
      if http_auth?
        http_auth
      else
        redirect
      end
    end
  end
```

goes inside initializers

```
 config.warden do |manager|
    manager.failure_app = CustomFailure
  end
```

goes inside `application.rb`

```
config.autoload_paths << Rails.root.join('lib')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1st off the code will NOT redirect your routes if the user is not logged in. That is a separate issue that can be fixed inside a custom controller inherited to registrations_controller. What this WILL do is redirect when a login has failed by the user. IE you type in the wrong password > redirects to new page.

for the first branch of code create an app called custom_failure.rb inside the lib folder (top level) and paste that code within.

for the second branch of code go into

> /Users/admin/acltc_projects/roomkick/config/initializers/devise.rb
>   search for

`warden do` with cmd f or ctrl f and remove the # on the warden do and "end" line.
paste the    `manager.failure_app = CustomFailure` right below warden do. under config/locals in application.rb add `config.autoload_paths << Rails.root.join('lib')` inside your module. 
Finally go back to the app inside lib and modify the line  `new_user_session_url(:subdomain => 'secure')` for the session_url you can modify this directly to whatever you want for a route. 
Restart your server and test the app.
Upvote if this helped!

Answer (score 0):

check devise documentation https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Redirect-to-a-specific-page-when-the-user-can-not-be-authenticated

> If a user is not authenticatable you can redirect to a specific page.
>
> For this example we want to use the entire URL with a particular
>   sub-domain. Devise uses the path not the entire URL by default. The
>   workaround is to use a custom failure app inherited from Devise
>   failure app.

```
class CustomFailure < Devise::FailureApp
    def redirect_url
       new_user_session_url(:subdomain => 'secure')
    end

    # You need to override respond to eliminate recall
    def respond
      if http_auth?
        http_auth
      else
        redirect
      end
    end
end
```

> And add the following in config/initializers/devise.rb:

```
  config.warden do |manager|
    manager.failure_app = CustomFailure
  end
```

Hope it'll help.